# onclick color changer JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, onclick

I am trying to apply a CSS propterty to a  tag when clicked by using a function, I plan on having the color change depending on how many times it has been clicked. However I'm receiving an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: colorChanger is not defined.

My HTML code:

```
<td onclick="colorChanger(this);">
```

My Javascript function

```
function colorChanger(){
style.backgroundColor = '#007d00';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. The only change you should make - your function need to accept parameter you pass:

```
function colorChanger(el){
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#007d00';
}
```

Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P8UTB/

Comment: No problem :) Glad the solution was helpful

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can try this:

```
function colorChanger(object){
    $(object).css("background-color","#ffffff");
}
```